# Can I make a clickable hyperlink from a C# comment to a Markdown file?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, markdown

I have a project that is largely C# and with some Markdown documentation. Sometimes I want to link from Markdown to C# classes ("this is implemented here..."), and sometimes I want to link from a C# comment to Markdown ("for explanation, see here..."). The first (linking from MD to CS) is easy enough. I am having trouble with the second (linking from CS to MD).

Ideally I would like:

1. Markdown references from CS comments should be clickable hyperlinks in Visual Studio (and preferably also Visual Studio code and the GitHub browser-based UI).
2. The compiler should warn me if a link points to a nonexistent file.
3. If I cannot achieve 2, then at least there should be an easy way for me to implement a unit test that scans the code, finds these CS-to-MD links and checks them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you found anything in the meanwhile?